# Getting a different result from query with active records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have tables with UTC dates. When trying to get the day of week by using dow in PostgreSQL, I get the wrong day if the hours flow to the next day (and I need the right dow).

I created a fiddle to show the problem:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9aa9e/11

If I run the queries locally on my pgAdmin, it will return the correct dow. But on fiddle and from rails, I get the wrong dow. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably a timezone issue. Rails does all its database work in UTC, pgAdmin is probably setting a timezone on the database session.

Comment: Yes, I knew it was a timezone issue. But I have also found a solution, posting it as an answer in case someone else encounters it.

Comment: Yeah, timezones are the devil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I understood that pgAdmin does it's own dow magic based on my timezone, and when rails sends that, it obviously doesn't happen. 
The system I work on relies on the fact that rails does it's conversion magic for UTC datetimes back and forth, which work great if you don't use local postgreSQL timezone related functions such as DOW. What I did not is that it worked fine if I gave the dow the right offset. So here's my solution to the problem if anyone else needs it:

```
utc_diff = Time.current.time_zone.utc_offset/60/60
# making sure the diff is either  + or - (minus is automatic) 
utc_diff = utc_diff < 0 ? utc_diff : "+#{utc_diff}"
dow_part = "EXTRACT(DOW FROM punches.punched_in_at at time zone 'UTC#{utc_diff}') as dow"
```

So there you have it, hope it helps others.